# URL not working in facebook like box

Tags: facebook-likebox

I need to include a facebook likebox in a site, so I went to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and used that wizar to get my likebox up and running.
When I put into url field the correct value http://www.facebook.com/yurimuc I got the following error message

"Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

The url is real and works but is not working in that widget. Any idea about the reason?

Thanks in advance,

Farid

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Like Box social plugin intended to be used with Facebook Pages, [`yurimuc`](http://www.facebook.com/yurimuc) however is a user account not a page.

Comment: Thanks, I had noticed that and switched to fan page instead personal profile.